# Cannot find the file specified error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a windows script that asks the user for their name and username.
When I run it in cmd it comes back with the error message "Cannot find the file specified."

Here is the code:

```
@echo off

title User Records System
ECHO Welcome to the User Records System

SET /P <name>=[Please enter you full name.]
REM if %name% = nul goto :label6
pause

SET /P <uName>=[Please enter your username.]
REM if %uName% = nul goto :label10
pause

ECHO %date%_%time% %name% >>C:\user_records.txt
ECHO %date%_%time% %uName% >>C:\user_records.txt
ECHO %date%_%time% %time% >>C:\user_records.txt
pause
```

I am aware that the fix is very obvious I'm just very new to this.
Also if you have any other suggested improvements please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In batch files the angular brackets are redirection operators, so

```
            v.................................... write to file "=[Pl..."
SET /P <name>=[Please enter you full name.]
       ^......................................... read from file "name"
```

You should use something like

```
SET "name="
SET /p "name=[Please enter you full name.]"
if not defined name goto :label6

SET "uName="
SET /P "uName=[Please enter your username.]"
if not defined uName goto :label10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
set /p name= "[Please enter your full name.]"
if not defined name goto :label6
pause

set /p uName= "[Please enter your username.]"
if not defined uName goto :label10
pause
```

That way you only have to type "set" once. Just a little short cut. FYI, I recommend putting the space after the equals sign.